# Cannot find delphi application .exe file

Tags: delphi

I have been coding a project in Delphi but after adding some rudimentary code (nothing that should've affected the actual project file) the window stopped coming up but in my task manager it says that the project is running. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Find your app on the Details tab of Task Manager, then right-mouse click it.  From the context menu, you can then choose `Open file location` to find out where it is and `End task` to shut it down.  If the app was started by the Delphi IDE, you can close it by using `Run | Program Reset` or `Ctrl-F2`.

Comment: One of the first thing I'd suspect would be an infinite loop before the main form is displayed, which could be the case if task manager shows a cpu usage corresponding to a full core.  But without more details, I don't think anybody here can really help you.  That would be a guessing game.

Comment: What Delphi version and Framework (VCL vs FMX) do you use? In Delphi 10.4.2 there is a bug in FMX (RSP-33382) that may cause such problems on a computer with two or more high-density screens (Scale > 100%).

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions, I fixed it with the help of my Teacher :)